# Tilde not expanded when quoting on the right hand side of a Bash variable assignment

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, double-quotes, tilde-expansion

I have made a directory ~/test_myDir

I then run the following bash script:

```
x="myDir"

dirName="~/test_$x"

cd $dirName
echo "hey" > test.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
test.sh: line 5: cd: ~/test_myDir: No such file or directory
```

I then remove the quotes from the second assignment:

```
x="myDir"

dirName=~/test_$x

cd $dirName
echo "hey" > test.txt
```

The script runs without error.

What is going on here?  I ran into this issue in a larger, more complicated script, and I narrowed it down to my use of quotes in a variable assignment that contained another variable.

Still, from the error message, it looks like the full path is being expanded correctly in the "cd" call.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't consider tilde as the potential problem here, so I didn't think to search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation marks prevent expansion of `~`. Replace `~` with `$HOME` or use `dirName=~/"test_$x"`.

From the manual's explanation of tilde expansion:

> Each variable assignment is checked for **unquoted** tilde-prefixes immediately following a : or the first =.  In these cases, tilde expansion is
>          also performed.